# How do I set mouse double click speed in Lubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, openbox, settings, lxde

I'm using Lubuntu 11.10. The only problem I have that the mouse double click speed is a bit high (it seems to me that it is around 100-200ms) and I would like it to set it to around 500ms. Is there a way to do it? I tried using Openbox Configuration Manager but that only changes the double click speed for window headers. But in PCManFM for example it is still around 200ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to system>preference>mouse, in the "double-click timeout" section set the double-click speed.

there is more advanced ways to configure it but it seems this one can resolve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the answer

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1920761&highlight=double+click

It's a separate setting for java programs (netbeans for example). For that create a file called .Xresources and/or .Xdefaults. Add to both of them this line `*.multiClickTime: 750`. 750ms is the double click speed. You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

For Lubuntu access the following menu/dialog:

1. LXDE button -> Preferences -> Openbox Configuration Manager -> Mouse
2. Then change "double click timeout" to "750"